# What does the A stand for in the type designation for GE THQAL Breakers?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Are the (old) GE Type **THQAL** breakers allowed to be used in modern **GE PowerMark Gold** load centers?

What does the **A** stand for in the type designation? I noticed that it is for 60C wire. Is this the only difference from type *THQL*?

The load center is GE model *TM3220CCU2K* and it calls for the following breaker types: *THQP, THQL, THQLAF, THQLGF, THHQL, THHQLAF, THHQGF, TQDL, THQDL, TXQL*.

Could it be that GE do not mention type **THQAL** because it is no longer being made, but it would still be ok to use it in these newer load centers?

The breaker I have is *THQAL21100* and it was used in an old GE load center as the main breaker. Would it be compatible with the modern GE tin plated copper bus?

Related question:
[Backfeeding a main breaker panel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/268561/backfeeding-a-main-breaker-panel)

Comment: Quick websearch isn't finding THQAL  at all. There is probably a page somewhere on GE's site that enumerates the letter codes... At a wild guess, compatible with aluminum wire?

Comment: Usually you can only use the listed breakers in a panel(some exceptions I think).  There might be design changes between the old breaker and new panels.  Probably the best people to ask is GE.

Comment: Is it a *main* breaker or does it go in branch circuit spaces?

Comment: If this is the same panel as in your other question should add a link to that question so people have an idea of what you are doing.

Comment: The breaker in question was a factory installed main breaker at the top of the panel. I want to use it on a different panel as a backfed breaker, so it will go in branch circuit spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted ABB (who now make GE breakers) and this is the reply:

> Not sure what the " A" stood for, but since the THQL replaced the
> THQAL, should work.